# Tomcat and JMeter generating HTTP 404 errors

Tags: http, tomcat, http-status-code-404, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm a complete novice with JMeter. I'm trying to use JMeter to connect to a web application deployed in Tomcat to simulate a small number of users logging in and browsing a page.

When I ran the test plan, JMeter log showed a series of HTTP 404 messages indicating that there was a communications problem somewhere.

The following link shows the test plan's HTTP defaults:

[alt text http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/uploads/HTTP_Defaults.PNG](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/uploads/HTTP_Defaults.PNG)

With two simple HTTP requests to follow.

The first request should enable the users to log in:

[alt text http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/uploads/Login.PNG](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/uploads/Login.PNG)

And the second request should allow the newly logged in users to browse a page:

[alt text http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/uploads/Browse.PNG](http://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~martin/uploads/Browse.PNG)

But, as I said, all I received in the JMeter logs were HTTP 404 messages:

```
2009/09/23 15:10:43 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler: Error Response Code: 404
```

Tomcat is running during the test and in the test plan, I also have a HTTP Cookie Manager set to 'default'.

When my application runs under Tomcat in test, its URL is `http://localhost:8080/myDataSharer` and I'm trying to have JMeter reflect this.

Any help would be welcome as I can't work out why JMeter and Tomcat aren't talking to each other.

Thanks

Martin

Comment: Another thing that looks extrange is the path of the Login request. Is that URL correct? Shouldn't it be j_acegi_security_check? Is that the url that appears in the action of the login form?

Comment: Are you using Acegi or Spring Security?

Comment: Neither. My application uses default Apache Tomcat security.

Comment: ok, I don't know why I supposed it. Anyway I added more info to my answer.

Comment: Well I've tried what you asked. But JMeter refuses to log in and when I try a manual log in at http://localhost:8080/examples/jsp/security/protected/login.jsp, I'm given a 404 error perhaps because there is no page to go to after the security check.

Adapting your test plan for my application, JMeter still refuses to allow me in.

I find it odd though that specifying a user in Tomcat's users.xml file should cvhange things though. I am trying to simualte normal users who won't be defined in this file anyway but in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **path** in **HTTP Request Defaults** is not added at the beginning of the **path** in **HTTP Request**. Add the context root **myDataSharer** to the path in **HTTP Request**.
If you don't want to repeat it everywere, there is a **Configuration Element** where you can define proeprties and later reference it like this **${my.propertie}**.
Also you should add an element that shows request and response data, I think it's called **Result Tree** or something like that.

**Edit 1:** Another thing that looks extrange is the **path** of the Login request. Is that URL correct? Shouldn't it be `j_acegi_security_check`? Is that the url that appears in the action of the login form?

**Edit 2:** In Tomcat there is an example application used to test security:
http://example.com:8080/examples/jsp/security/protected/login.jsp

The users are in **conf/tomcat-users.xml**. Add one with the role: **role1** like this:

```
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="test" password="test" roles="role1"/>
```

Start the server and you should be able to login. Then try this **JMeter test plan**:

```
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="1.8">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Plan de Pruebas" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Grupo de Hilos" enabled="true">
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.start_time">1157555458000</longProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">stoptest</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">0</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
        </elementProp>
        <longProp name="ThreadGroup.end_time">1157555458000</longProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <CookieManager guiclass="CookiePanel" testclass="CookieManager" testname="Gestor de Cookies HTTP" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="CookieManager.clearEachIteration">false</boolProp>
          <collectionProp name="CookieManager.cookies"/>
        </CookieManager>
        <hashTree/>
        <HTTPSampler guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSampler" testname="Petición HTTP" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.FILE_NAME"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/examples/jsp/security/protected/login.jsp</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.FILE_FIELD"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.mimetype"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol"></stringProp>
        </HTTPSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <HTTPSampler guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSampler" testname="Petición HTTP" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.FILE_NAME"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/examples/jsp/security/protected/j_security_check</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">POST</stringProp>
          <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
            <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">j_username</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">test</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
              <elementProp name="" elementType="HTTPArgument">
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.use_equals">true</boolProp>
                <boolProp name="HTTPArgument.always_encode">false</boolProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.name">j_password</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.value">test</stringProp>
                <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
              </elementProp>
            </collectionProp>
          </elementProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.FILE_FIELD"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.mimetype"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">8080</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.monitor">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
        </HTTPSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <ResultCollector guiclass="ViewResultsFullVisualizer" testclass="ResultCollector" testname="Ver Árbol de Resultados" enabled="true">
          <objProp>
            <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
              <time>true</time>
              <latency>true</latency>
              <timestamp>true</timestamp>
              <success>true</success>
              <label>true</label>
              <code>true</code>
              <message>true</message>
              <threadName>true</threadName>
              <dataType>true</dataType>
              <encoding>false</encoding>
              <assertions>true</assertions>
              <subresults>true</subresults>
              <responseData>false</responseData>
              <samplerData>false</samplerData>
              <xml>false</xml>
              <fieldNames>false</fieldNames>
              <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
              <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
              <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
              <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>false</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
              <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
            </value>
            <name>saveConfig</name>
          </objProp>
          <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
          <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
        </ResultCollector>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

Look that I added an extra request before loging in to get the cookie. If you don't do that login will fail with a 408 code.

**If you get this to work then your application can be tested in the same way.**

Comment: Thanks. This has helped a lot. But using the Result Tree, I see same HTML for the browseCommunities request as I do for the Login request. To me this seems as if the log in request isn't actually logging in. Any forther help would be welcome.

Comment: I've tried /myDataSharer/ and /myDataSharer/j_security_check/ and /myDataSharer/j_acegi/security_check/ for the path. But none of these works.

Comment: Is not /myDataSharer/j_security_check/ it is /myDataSharer/j_security_check

Comment: Even with the login request's path set as /myDataSharer/j_security_check it still won't log me in.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have this thing working - it was a case of changing Redirect Automatically to Follow Redirects in the requests. Thanks to Rodrigoap for his assistance